# Small caps in title but not for words like "of"

Tags: titles, small-caps

I want the command `\textsc` but not for all words (words like "of" or "to" should be set the normal way without small caps).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \textsc{Contribution submission to the conference}
\end{document}
```

How can I use the command `\textsc` and automate this small caps thing? How does it work if I use `\title` and `\@title` to place/create my title?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?  Using `\textsc{submission}`, "submission" will be set in all lowercase small caps font shape, rather than uppercase "S" and lowercase "ubmission".  It would seem you are not talking about issues of auto-capitalization of words (as in the case I just mention), but rather about using a roman (upright) font versus a small-caps font...Is that a correct understanding of your question?  By the way, welcome to the site.

Comment: Which engine do you use btw?

Comment: Which of these two cases are you seeking the result to look like? `\textsc{Contribution submission \textup{to} the conference}` or `\textsc{Contribution Submission to The Conference}`?  If the second case, see the `titlecaps` package.

Comment: Note that it will look very strange if you want the `\textup{}` mixture, as your wording suggests.

Comment: @Steven: Thanks for the welcoming. I mean I want to have all letters like this: "CONTRIBUTION" but not words like "to" or "of".

Comment: What I would like to have is the second way for the word "to" but all other characters should be like the first one of the other words. I mean that "Contribution" is completely uppercase and "to" is like we get it with "textsc" command lowercase.

Comment: @TeXnician: I use texlive on a Mac.

Comment: So you are looking for `titlecaps`?

Comment: You would like to get [this image (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W179S.png)? It makes no sense, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is still not quite clear what the OP seeks, but here I show what the `titlecaps` package can accomplish, which is:

1. capitalizing the first letter of each word
2. excluding a specified list of words from capitalization, using `\Addlcwords`.

Here is an example, shown in small-caps and upright shapes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\begin{document}
\Addlcwords{to the}
\titlecap{\textsc{Contribution submission to the conference}}

\titlecap{Contribution submission to the conference}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**FOLLOW UP**

In the end, this seems to be what the OP wanted.  I don't know of a way to automate it, but it is not particularly difficult to do manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textsc{CONTRIBUTION SUBMISSION to the CONFERENCE}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I *think* the OP is after `\textsc{Contribution submission} to the \textsc{conference}`.

Comment: @Werner I too saw that as a possibility, but as cfr pointed out, that "will look very strange."

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The first one is near what I'm looking for. All letters should be in upper-case letters ("to" or "the" as well) but they should have exactly the same size except of "to" or "the". They should be in upper-case as well but smaller than the other main words. I don't want the first letters of any Word higher than the others. Is it clearer?

Comment: @Mike1993 Do you mean something like `\textsc{CONTRIBUTION SUBMISSION to the CONFERENCE}`?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. It's crazy but this didn't come to my mind. Perhaps it is too easy.